# Magento 2 Product not available for purchase when qty=0

Tags: php, module, magento2, stock

Default magento shows out of stock for qty 0, And if admin set display out of stock product set to No, then Magento will not show out of stock product..

My requirement is i can show a message that " This product is no longer available for purchase" but only certain category like "overstock sale" category and it can be manage totally form admin. i am using back order for all products.
**where:**

- Product should show.
- Add to cart should hide.
- And message should show instead of Out of Stock.

Suggest any extension or any code.
Thanks in advance.

my effort is https://github.com/saif-bin-zahid/soldout
but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can override following code
vendor/magento/module-inventory-source-deduction-api/Model/SourceDeductionService.php

you can update following code

// if (($sourceItem->getQuantity() - $qty) >= 0) {
//}

Make sure to override above class in your custom module instead to make direct change in vendor as during upgrade you will lost the customization if you make direct change in vendor.

Comment: Thanks for you reply but I am not using MSI module.